# How can I add extra space before \cline in a \multicolumn matrix cell?

Tags: matrices, cline

I'm trying to make this matrix looks nicer. Currently the horizontal line coincides with the $A^\top$. How can I make it so $A^\top$ doesn't intersect with the horizontal line? This is what I have:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Original matrix:

\[
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{A^\top}\\ \cline{1-2}
            ~&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{A^\top}\\ \cline{2-2}
            ~&~&\ddots\\ \cline{4-4}
            ~&~&~&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{A^\top} \\
        \end{array} \right]
\]

Matrix with .25cm space after each row

\[
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{A^\top}\\[.25cm] \cline{1-2}
            ~&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{A^\top}\\[.25cm] \cline{2-2}
            ~&~&\ddots\\[.25cm] \cline{4-4}
            ~&~&~&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{A^\top} \\[.25cm]
        \end{array} \right]
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrapped the `A^\top` in an `\addstackgap` (`stackengine` package).  The default vertical gap added is 3pt, which can be redefined (`\setstackgap{S}{5pt}`) or else overridden with an optional argument (`\addstackgap[5pt]{...}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,stackengine}
\stackMath
\begin{document}
Original matrix:

\[
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{A^\top}\\ \cline{1-2}
            ~&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\addstackgap{A^\top}}\\ \cline{2-2}
            ~&~&\ddots\\ \cline{4-4}
            ~&~&~&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\addstackgap{A^\top}} \\
        \end{array} \right]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With `{bNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

$\begin{bNiceMatrix}[margin,cell-space-top-limit=2pt]
\Block[borders={bottom,right}]{}{A^\top} & \\
       & \Block[draw]{}{A^\top} & \\
       &        & \ddots \\
       &        &        & \Block[borders={top,left}]{}{A^\top} \\
\end{bNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility  with `bigstrut` `cellspace`  and `booktabs`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{cellspace} %

\begin{document}

Original matrix:

\[
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
            \multicolumn{1}{c|}{A^\top}\\ \cline{1-2}
            ~&\multicolumn{1}{|c|}{A^\top}\\ \cline{2-2}
            ~&~&\ddots\\ \cline{4-4}
            ~&~&~&\multicolumn{1}{|c}{A^\top} \\
        \end{array} \right]
\]
\vskip1cm
\[ \setlength{\aboverulesep}{0pt}\setlength{\belowrulesep}{0pt}
\setlength{\cmidrulewidth}{0.4pt}\bigstrutjot=4pt
\begin{bmatrix}
        \multicolumn{1}{c|}{A^{\top}\bigstrut[t]}\\ \cmidrule(l{0.35em}){1-2}
         &\multicolumn{1}{!{\kern-0.4pt\vrule}c|}{A^{\top}\bigstrut[t]}\\[-0.4pt] \cmidrule{2-2}
         & & \ddots\\ \cmidrule(r{0.35em}){4-4}
         & & &\multicolumn{1}{|c}{A^{\top}\bigstrut}
    \end{bmatrix} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]